# Is there a way to get automatic cascading delete for DDIC-tables?

Tags: abap, opensql

Is it possible to trigger a cascading delete for a table with a foreign key relation to another table? DDIC allows defining foreign key relations, which could (in theory) be used to implement cascading delete.

Comment: I guess one *could* bypass the ABAP layer altogether and implement such a trigger directly on the database. But I would consider that a really bad idea. Any other ABAP-developer looking at what you built will assume that any logic like that is implemented on the ABAP layer, and a database entry just "magically" disappearing when one in another table gets deleted would confuse the heck out of them. It's something you just don't do in the ABAP world.

Comment: couldnt agree more with Philipp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no database triggers in SAP. So you can't react to an operation on a database immediately. However you could create a job that runs from time to time to check the foreign keys.

I wouldn't recommand doing this with standard tables, though. You never know what kind of operations are allowed in the SAP standard, where there might be a foreign key relation without the key beeing defined in the other table. SAP is just weird sometimes.

If you wanna do it for your custom developments and expand on it dynamically, sure. You can check the DB `DD08L` for foreign key relations. However the table also holds all structures which have checktables, so you'd have to filter those. The DB `DD02L` can help with that (field `TABCLASS` defines the kind of object).